Why do we use a monomial basis to construct common orthogonal polynomials?
I'm new to the topic. I noticed most textbooks about orthogonal polynomials start the derivation by stating: "let's start with a basis of monomials and use Gram Schmidt algorithm to obtain orthogonal polynomials". It sounds a bit arbitrary. I get that monomials are easy to work with and they are linearly independent, so suitable as a good starting point. But is there any additional significance to what basis we choose as a starting point? Conceivably any linearly independent basis could be used to construct orthogonal polynomials, but I'm not sure if I can construct, let's say Hermtie polynomials, by using the same weight function and the basic version of Gram Schmidt, when the basis is not monomials. So in other words, do Hermite polynomials come up just because of the weight function I chose? Or because of the combination of the weight function and the basis? Is the form of the weight function somehow tied to the original basis when we want to obtain Hermite polynomials? Those are just different perspectives on my original question, and I'm just using Hermite to form a more concrete example.
